# What can I do with the snacks collected from NPCs?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In *GTA V*, if I kill NPCs as well as money they sometimes drop snacks as well. What can I do with the snack that I collect? Sell it? So far I’ve not found any use for it, or can’t see any use for it.

Comment: Are you talking about *GTA Online*? Well, those can be regarded as mini-health-packs. If you pick them up, your health recovers a little bit.

Comment: It's definitely snacks, not "smack".

Comment: Damn. I thought it was smack. The “+1 Snack” blurb flashes so fast I read it as “Smack”, being GTA an’ all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set your L3+R3/LS+RS to eat a snack which recovers a small amount of health (~5%).  You cannot use this action if you are out of snacks.  You can also do this through the action menu (hold select).

As a side note, you can  buy snacks from gas stations/convenience stores (the ones you rob) if you go up the register and hit right on the dpad.

Answer (score 1):

those snacks are invaluable during a mission, when you are about to die they can give you back your full health, just hide somewhere and eat a meteorite or 2, and the mission continues

Answer (score 1):

Those snacks you pick up from NPCs are entirely different from the ego chasers, meteorites etc that you buy from gas stations and stores. The store bought items are accessible under the 'snacks' menu in your interaction menu and can fully recover your health. The snacks you pick up from NPCs are consumed when you use the 'eat snack' action. They allow you to recover 50% of your health.

Comment: That’s really great advice on the distinction between the two types. Thanks!